# I want to create lists of racer's times on a seperate file using code on another python file

Tags: python, list

`enter code here`Basically, I want to be able to have 2 different files, one with code, one with the times. Every time I enter a runner's name i want it to either

A. Create a new name and times
Like so:
`runner1 = [23:43:15, 18:14:16]`

**OR**

B. Update a runners info and add a time to it
Like so:
`runner1 = [23:43:15, 18:14:16] but add 19:16:18 to it`

But I really need it to save to another file, so even if i shut off the program, it will still save. Everything needs to be updated, no new lists should be created (Unless it doesn't already exist)

Any help would really be appreciated as i have lost countless hours of sleep attempting this!
Here is the code I already have:

````
Racename = input("Name of the race")
runnerstxt = open("runners.py", "a")
runnerstxt.write(Racename + '\n')
while True:
  runnernameandtime = []
  runnerName = input("What was the racer's name? ")
  runnernameandtime.append(runnerName)
  runnerTime = input("What was the racer's time? ")
  runnernameandtime.append(runnerTime)
  runnerstxt.write(str(runnernameandtime))
  runnerstxt.write("\n")
  runnernameandtime.clear()```
````

Comment: Is `runner1` going to be a list that you use? If so, you can save it using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) library. Makes it easy to read it back as well. You should provide more code as to what you're doing in your main file

Comment: Alright, I will edit that, hopefully that will clear it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume that all your data will be stored in a file called `race_data.pickle`. We will store all the data in a single dictionary and then can access everything that has previously been stored.

```
import pickle
# Check if a file exists

try:
    # Previous file found, loading it
    race_data = pickle.load(open("race_data.pickle", "rb"))
except (OSError, IOError) as e:
    race_data = {}

Racename = input("Name of the race")
#Check if the race has previously been registered
if Racename not in race_data.keys():
    #Add if not registered
    race_data[Racename] = {}

while True:
    runnerName = input("What was the racer's name? ")
    #Check if the runner has been registered
    if runnerName not in race_data[Racename].keys():
        #Add empty if not registered
        race_data[Racename][runnerName] = []
    #Add the runner's time in the list
    runnerTime = input("What was the racer's time? ")
    race_data[Racename][runnerName].append(runnerTime)

    #Save the latest data into the pickle
    with open("race_data.pickle", "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump(race_data, f)
```

You can kill the program at any time and it will have the data from the previous time the object was stored. A sample of how the data will be stored is as follows:

```
{
 'Race1': {
            'Racer1': ['3', '10'], 
            'Racer2': ['5', '22'], 
            'Racer3': ['20']
           }, 
 'Race2': {
            'Racer4': ['10'], 
            'Racer1': ['20'], 
            'Racer10': ['44']
           }
}
```

Comment: Thats weird, it throws this error, ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
    race_data = pickle.load(open("race_data.pickle", "rb"))
EOFError: Ran out of input ```